# Angular Ivy: read module providers

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I'm trying to lazy load a component in Angular Ivy

```
import("./app/products/products.module").then((module) => {
  console.log(module.ProductsModule.ngInjectorDef.providers);
});
```

The module code

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { LazyComponent } from "./lazy/lazy.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations   : [LazyComponent],
  imports        : [
    CommonModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    LazyComponent
  ],
  providers      : [
    {
      provide : "components",
      useValue: {
        lazy: LazyComponent,
      }
    }
  ]
})
export class ProductsModule {
}
```

I was able to access the providers using `module.ProductsModule.ngInjectorDef.providers`, but I'm looking for a better method

Maybe somthing like `module.ProductsModule.ngInjectorDef.get("components")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ivy has a private function called `createInjector`, it's exposed with theta in the current API, but will be exposed later when Ivy gets stable.

Assume you've got such code:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LazyComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'components',
      useValue: {
        lazy: LazyComponent
      }
    }
  ],
  entryComponents: [LazyComponent]
})
export class LazyModule {
  static getLazyComponents: () => { lazy: typeof LazyComponent };

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    LazyModule.getLazyComponents = () => injector.get('components');
  }
}
```

Let's lazy load the `LazyModule` via dynamic import:

```js
import { ɵcreateInjector as createInjector, Injector } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(({ LazyModule }) => {
      createInjector(LazyModule, injector);
      console.log(LazyModule.getLazyComponents());
    });
  }
}
```

But using this approach - you lazy load a module. If you want to lazy load component - you can do it without using module, assume this `LazyComponent`, that's located inside `lazy.component.ts` file:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lazy',
  template: `
    <h1>I am lazy</h1>
  `
})
export class LazyComponent {}
```

You can use a dynamic import to load this component + `renderComponent` function:

```js
import { ɵrenderComponent as renderComponent, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-lazy></app-lazy>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    import('./lazy.component').then(({ LazyComponent }) => {
      renderComponent(LazyComponent, {
        injector,
        host: 'app-lazy'
      });
    });
  }
}
```

One note - lazy components DON'T HAVE lifecycle! `constructor` will be invoked, but not such hooks as `ngOnInit`, `ngOnDestroy` etc.

Returning to your question about lazy module - you would probably want to expose the component factories of those lazy components, something like that:

```js
export class LazyModule {
  static getComponentFactories: () => {
    lazy: ComponentFactory<LazyComponent>;
  };

  constructor(resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    LazyModule.getComponentFactories = () => ({
      lazy: resolver.resolveComponentFactory(LazyComponent)
    });
  }
}
```

If you do not want to use static functions, you can declare instance methods:

```js
export class LazyModule {
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  public getComponentFactories() {
    return {
      lazy: this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(LazyComponent)
    };
  }
}
```

And then get an instance of this module:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(({ LazyModule }) => {
      const injector = createInjector(LazyModule, this.injector);
      const lazyModule = injector.get(LazyModule);
      console.log(lazyModule.getComponentFactories());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't figure out `ɵcreateInjector` in a hundred years :D

Comment: @UnLoCo haha :D yeah, I advice you just explore Ivy's API by copying that theta symbol and just `ctrl + f` :D tho I was doing that :D